# How do I echo each value of a foreach loop?

Tags: php, html

Not sure if the question title actually makes sense.

Anyway, what I'd like to do is be able to echo an individual value from a foreach loop.

Here's my code:

```
$headlines = array('primary_headline' => $_POST['primary_headline'], 'secondary_headline' => $_POST['secondary_headline'], 'primary_subline' => $_POST['primary_subline'], 'secondary_subtext' => $_POST['secondary_subtext']);
$city_name = "Dallas";
$ref_name = "Facebook";
$searches = array('$city_name', '$ref_name');
$replacements = array($city_name, $ref_name);
if(isset($headlines)) {
  foreach($headlines as $headline) {
      $headline = str_replace($searches, $replacements, $headline);
      echo($headline['primary_headline']); // I thought this would do the trick
  }
}
```

I thought that this would've echoed `my city is Dallas` when `my city is $city_name` was posted, unfortunately, this isn't the case and it merely echoes `msps`, which is the first letter of each input value:

```
<input name="primary_headline" type="text" value="my city is $city_name" />
<input name="secondary_headline" type="text" value="secondary headline" />
<input name="primary_subline" type="text" value="primary subline" />
<input name="secondary_subtext" type="text" value="secondary subline" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated!! :)

Comment: var_dump() is your friend in cases like this. It will show you the structure of your array and allow you to work basic questions like this out for yourself. http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: I figured it out, I didn't realize the usage of `foreach()` at first, but after properly going through it's entry in the php.net manual, I realized that I needed to assign a reference to the original array by using `foreach($headlines as &$headline) and thus updating the array with any values created within the `foreach()` loop, instead of copying them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For good measure figured I should close this question with an answer (I've already placed it in the comments section as I couldn't add an answer).

The ampersand (&) must be used in order to assign a reference to the original array `$headlines` instead of copying it's valuables, thus updating it with any values created within the `foreach()` loop.

So, my code is now;

```
$headlines = array('primary_headline' => $_POST['primary_headline'], 'secondary_headline' => $_POST['secondary_headline'], 'primary_subline' => $_POST['primary_subline'], 'secondary_subtext' => $_POST['secondary_subtext']);
$city_name = "Dallas";
$ref_name = "Facebook";
$searches = array('$city_name', '$ref_name');
$replacements = array($city_name, $ref_name);
if(isset($headlines)) {
  foreach($headlines as &$headline) {
      $headline = str_replace($searches, $replacements, $headline);
  }
echo ($headlines['primary_headline']) // This now has the value of $_POST['primary_headline'] along with the str_replace() function assigned to $headline  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
echo($headline['primary_headline']); // I thought this would do the trick
```

To

```
echo($headline) . PHP_EOL; // I thought this would do the trick
```

When you are using foreach you do not need to specify an index to the element, because foreach will handle iterating for you, so when you dereference something inside the loop, you are asking for a character from the string.  Here you get the first character because 'primary_headline' is being interpreted as a 0.

Comment: That echoes all four values created in the foreach loop though, I'm merely looking to echo the individual values, for example `echo($headlines['primary_headline'])` echoes the post data for `primary_headline`. The foreach loop is there to replace `$city_name` and `$ref_name` with their true variables.

Comment: I think I've perhaps misunderstood how `foreach()` works, and in turned kind of screwed my question. I'm not looking to have each value echoed with a line break, but to be able to assign each value to a single variable or array key (if `arr['primary_headline']` is what an array key is), so that they can be used individually, e.g. in one part of a webpage I can have `<?php echo($primary_headline); ?>`, another `<?php echo($secondary_headline); ?>` etc.

I'd very much like to thank you for all your inputs and edits though :).

Comment: Glad you figured it out, hope that I helped point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

```
$searches = array('$city_name', '$ref_name');
```

The single quotes are making $searches literally contain the word `$city_name`, not the VALUE of $city_name. You don't need quotes while assigning variables:

```
$searches = array($city_name, $ref_name);
```

unless, of course, you're doing some kind of templating system and trying to do variable interpolation without eval().

Comment: I was told that I needed to do `str_replace('$city_name', $city_name, $_POST['form_field']);` as what I wanted is for users to input the term $city_name, which would be replaced in value by the actual variable $city_name.

Answer (score 1):

```
$headlines = array('primary_headline' => $_POST['primary_headline'], 'secondary_headline' => $_POST['secondary_headline'], 'primary_subline' => $_POST['primary_subline'], 'secondary_subtext' => $_POST['secondary_subtext']);
```

This creates an array with `key=>value` pairs, not a multidimensional array.  Looping through this array in a `foreach` loop will return only the values, i.e. `$_POST['primary_headline']` for the first iteration, `$_POST['secondary_headline']` for the second iteration, etc.  This is why you're unable to access `$headline['primary_headline']`.

If you want to access "my city is Dallas" per your example, simply echo `$headlines['primary_headline']`.

If you want to echo each value:

```
foreach($headlines as $headline) {
  echo $headline . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: `$headlines['primary_headline']` doesn't echo `my city is Dallas` which is the problem, even after the foreach loop is still echos `my city is $city_name`.

Comment: $headline = str_replace($searches, $replacements, $headline);
echo $headline;